# Visual Studio 2022 - SSIS packages - XML with multiple namespace for a large number of files

Tags: xml, ssis

I have 400 xml files and I need upload data into MSSQL database. I use XML Source package and I get this error message: Unable to infer the XSD from the XML file. The XML contains multiple namespaces.

Here is an example of one record in XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Action xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" exportType="manual" eventType="regular">
  <eventId xmlns="http://magicware.cz/XmlSchemas/ExportMagicWareToPCR">503</eventId>
  <name xmlns="http://magicware.cz/XmlSchemas/ExportMagicWareToPCR">Media</name>
  <code xmlns="http://magicware.cz/XmlSchemas/ExportMagicWareToPCR">942082ab</code>
  <organizer xmlns="http://magicware.cz/XmlSchemas/ExportMagicWareToPCR">Office</organizer>
  <dateFrom xmlns="http://magicware.cz/XmlSchemas/ExportMagicWareToPCR">2022-01-01</dateFrom>
  <dateTo xmlns="http://magicware.cz/XmlSchemas/ExportMagicWareToPCR">2022-12-31</dateTo>
  <Person>
    <participant>
      <participantId xmlns="http://magicware.cz/XmlSchemas/ExportMagicWareToPCR">22213</participantId>
      <role xmlns="http://magicware.cz/XmlSchemas/ExportMagicWareToPCR">AV Technician</role>
      <personalInfo xmlns="http://magicware.cz/XmlSchemas/ExportMagicWareToPCR">
        <gender>M</gender>
        <firstName>Sam</firstName>
        <lastName>Johnes</lastName>
        <maidenName>Johnes</maidenName>
        <birthDate>1989-12-01</birthDate>
        <birthCountry>USA</birthCountry>
        <birthPlace>New York</birthPlace>
        <citizenshipCountry>US</citizenshipCountry>
        <nin>2542215</nin>
        <email>sam.j@loks.com</email>
        <phone>8541254785</phone>
        <idCardNo>54852</idCardNo>
        <documentValidTo>2030-06-30</documentValidTo>
        <addressCountry>USA</addressCountry>
        <addressCity>Alabama</addressCity>
        <addressStreet>Horn st.</addressStreet>
        <addressZip>16500</addressZip>
      </personalInfo>
      <mediaInfo xmlns="http://magicware.cz/XmlSchemas/ExportMagicWareToPCR" />
      <photo xmlns="http://magicware.cz/XmlSchemas/ExportMagicWareToPCR"></photo>
      <Result>
        <HitRob>true</HitRob>
      </Result>
    </participant>
```

Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pre-process XML files by using XSLT transformation to remove namespaces.

SSIS has for that XML Task, operation XSLT.

Here is a generic XSLT to remove namespaces.

**Input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Action xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" exportType="manual" eventType="regular">
    <eventId xmlns="http://magicware.cz/XmlSchemas/ExportMagicWareToPCR">503</eventId>
    <name xmlns="http://magicware.cz/XmlSchemas/ExportMagicWareToPCR">Media</name>
    <code xmlns="http://magicware.cz/XmlSchemas/ExportMagicWareToPCR">942082ab</code>
    <organizer xmlns="http://magicware.cz/XmlSchemas/ExportMagicWareToPCR">Office</organizer>
    <dateFrom xmlns="http://magicware.cz/XmlSchemas/ExportMagicWareToPCR">2022-01-01</dateFrom>
    <dateTo xmlns="http://magicware.cz/XmlSchemas/ExportMagicWareToPCR">2022-12-31</dateTo>
    <Person>
        <participant>
            <participantId xmlns="http://magicware.cz/XmlSchemas/ExportMagicWareToPCR">22213</participantId>
            <role xmlns="http://magicware.cz/XmlSchemas/ExportMagicWareToPCR">AV Technician</role>
            <personalInfo xmlns="http://magicware.cz/XmlSchemas/ExportMagicWareToPCR">
                <gender>M</gender>
                <firstName>Sam</firstName>
                <lastName>Johnes</lastName>
                <maidenName>Johnes</maidenName>
                <birthDate>1989-12-01</birthDate>
                <birthCountry>USA</birthCountry>
                <birthPlace>New York</birthPlace>
                <citizenshipCountry>US</citizenshipCountry>
                <nin>2542215</nin>
                <email>sam.j@loks.com</email>
                <phone>8541254785</phone>
                <idCardNo>54852</idCardNo>
                <documentValidTo>2030-06-30</documentValidTo>
                <addressCountry>USA</addressCountry>
                <addressCity>Alabama</addressCity>
                <addressStreet>Horn st.</addressStreet>
                <addressZip>16500</addressZip>
            </personalInfo>
            <mediaInfo xmlns="http://magicware.cz/XmlSchemas/ExportMagicWareToPCR"/>
            <photo xmlns="http://magicware.cz/XmlSchemas/ExportMagicWareToPCR"></photo>
            <Result>
                <HitRob>true</HitRob>
            </Result>
        </participant>
    </Person>
</Action>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

   <!-- template to copy elements -->
   <xsl:template match="*">
      <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>

   <!-- template to copy attributes -->
   <xsl:template match="@*">
      <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
         <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:attribute>
   </xsl:template>

   <!-- template to copy the rest of the nodes -->
   <xsl:template match="comment() | text() | processing-instruction()">
      <xsl:copy/>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Action exportType="manual" eventType="regular">
  <eventId>503</eventId>
  <name>Media</name>
  <code>942082ab</code>
  <organizer>Office</organizer>
  <dateFrom>2022-01-01</dateFrom>
  <dateTo>2022-12-31</dateTo>
  <Person>
    <participant>
      <participantId>22213</participantId>
      <role>AV Technician</role>
      <personalInfo>
        <gender>M</gender>
        <firstName>Sam</firstName>
        <lastName>Johnes</lastName>
        <maidenName>Johnes</maidenName>
        <birthDate>1989-12-01</birthDate>
        <birthCountry>USA</birthCountry>
        <birthPlace>New York</birthPlace>
        <citizenshipCountry>US</citizenshipCountry>
        <nin>2542215</nin>
        <email>sam.j@loks.com</email>
        <phone>8541254785</phone>
        <idCardNo>54852</idCardNo>
        <documentValidTo>2030-06-30</documentValidTo>
        <addressCountry>USA</addressCountry>
        <addressCity>Alabama</addressCity>
        <addressStreet>Horn st.</addressStreet>
        <addressZip>16500</addressZip>
      </personalInfo>
      <mediaInfo />
      <photo />
      <Result>
        <HitRob>true</HitRob>
      </Result>
    </participant>
  </Person>
</Action>
```